# C# небезопасный буфер

Tags: c#

На https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zycewsya.aspx есть пример. Пример запускается, работает, но ни чего не выводит. Попробовал добавить в пример Console.WriteLine - не получилось:

```
  unsafe struct MyBuffer  
  {  
      public fixed char fixedBuffer[10];  
  }  

  unsafe class MyClass  
  {  
      public MyBuffer myBuffer = default(MyBuffer);  
  }  


  static void Main()  
  {  
      MyClass myC = new MyClass();  

      unsafe  
      {  
          fixed (char* charPtr = myC.myBuffer.fixedBuffer)  
          {  
             *charPtr = 'A';  
          }  
          Console.WriteLine(new string(myC.myBuffer.fixedBuffer)); // ошибка  
      }  

      Console.ReadLine();  
  }
```

Ругается:

> Невозможно использовать буферы фиксированного размера в нефиксированных выражениях. Попробуйте использовать оператор fixed.

Вопрос - как можно вывести "A"?

Comment: Вопрос зачем? При использовании небезопасного кода нужно везде ставить метку "небезопасный" и собирать сборку так же с меткой "небезопасный".

Comment: Похоже что "Попробуйте использовать оператор fixed" означает что к WriteLine нужно применить fixed.

Comment: _Вопрос - как можно вывести "A"?_ - перенеси вывод в блок fixed

Comment: _к WriteLine нужно применить fixed._
Можете привести пример - как?

Comment: _перенеси вывод в блок fixed_
Увы, не работает.

Comment: Простите, а _зачем_ вам unsafe-буфер?

Comment: _зачем вам unsafe-буфер?_ - реальный код гораздо больше, и нет смысла здесь его весь приводить. Выложил только то, что вызывало "затык". Наверное, проблему можно решить и иначе...

Comment: @S-type: Но тем не менее, зачем? Unsafe-буфер — очень специфическая, ужасно неудобная и редко нужная вещь, я бы избегал его в своей архитектуре как огня. Поэтому есть подозрение, что он на самом деле вам не нужен.

Comment: _Но тем не менее, зачем?_ Давайте глянем чуть шире - а зачем программировать, если есть есть более прибыльные вещи? Ведь само по себе программирование, это _очень специфическая, ужасно неудобная и редко нужная вещь_ :)

Comment: @S-type: Ну, обычно программисты стараются не создавать себе сложности, а наоборот избавляться от них. Вы, как мне кажется, делаете наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Надо

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(myC.myBuffer.fixedBuffer)); // ошибка
```

заменить на

```
MyBuffer tmp = myC.myBuffer;
Console.WriteLine(new string(tmp.fixedBuffer));
```

Теперь всё работает.